# How can I deploy Azure Functions to in-house datacenters?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

[This article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-functions/?v=17.23h) discusses that an Azure function can easily be deployed in local datacenters without Azure.

> Open source runtime that runs anywhere
>
> The Functions runtime, templates, UI and underlying WebJobs SDK are all open source projects being developed publically. The Azure Function runtime will be portable so you can run Functions anywhere - on Azure, **in your datacenter or other clouds.**

Question:

- How can I create an installer package that I can give to customers?
- What are the requirements of this installer?
- Can the target environment be ASP.NET core or run on Linux/Mac?

Comment: @PeterBons  I pasted a citation.

Comment: I know, just stumbled upon https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-runtime-overview with a link in the bottom to the installer. Just did not think it was possible but it seems like a very cool feature. Thanks for bringing this possibility to my attention!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Azure Functions Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-runtime-overview) (currently in preview) enables an on premise deployment of Azure Functions, which includes portal, functions execution runtime and other components, all in an installer you can use. This also removes some of the cloud dependencies like Azure Storage, allowing you to run all within your internal network.

Currently, .NET Core is not supported, so you'll need to deploy this on a Windows environment, but we're actively working on migrating the [core Azure Functions runtime bits](https://github.com/azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script) and the on premise Azure Functions Runtime would follow.

You can find the requirements on the document I've linked to.

Another option is do download the functions releases directly from the repository [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/releases), but that does not have an installer that enables an end-to-end deployment experience (or components like the portal), so you'd need to provide that.